# Bootstrapping on Cronbachs Alpha? - Is it a good idea?

Tags: bootstrap, reliability

One can calculate a BCa-CI of Cronbachs Alpha, e.g. using the {psy}-Package.

Is this generally a good idea?

You can read here about a simulation study in this matter.
http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2013/Vouliagmeni/CCC/CCC-25.pdf

The authors say: "Casella  and  Berger  (2001)  do  not  suggest  the  use  of  bootstrap methodology   for   estimating   the   variance   of   the 
variance.  We  cannot  say  with  certainty  that  this  is  the case for the alpha coefficient even though it is a function of variances." (p. 154)

Can you explain what's the matter about this?

Comment: The bootstrap protects against ignorance of the sampling distribution of the statistic at issue, but it is not robust against outliers from that distribution. Variances are more sensitive to this sort of thing than means, which may be why Casella and Berger are concerned. I hope someone can give a more authoritative explanation. Personally, I don't think the Cronbach is a particularly good idea, whether bootstrapped or not.

Comment: Thanks for this comment! Can another person elaborate further? Which alternative would you prefer to determine reliability of a scala, apart from Cronbach?

Comment: Confirmatory factor analysis to see if the purported factors are present. Or item response models to see if all items on the scale are performing as advertized. A pilot study to see if the measure actually performs as one hoped. There are many options. The Cronbach often delivers high values when the measure is actually fairly poor.

Comment: Is bootstrap assessment of the factor analysis a reasonable approach?